# apache brooklyn unable to provision port for web console

Tags: brooklyn, clocker

I have recently performed an update on my computer which seems to have broken apache brooklyn for me:

```html
brooklyn launch 
 ...
 WARN  Failed to start Brooklyn web-console (rethrowing): Unable to provision port for web console (wanted 8081-65535)
```

I am using the pre-compiled binaries: 0.7.0-M2-incubating
I have stopped and disabled ufw and iptables.

Any ideas appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Problem resolved... but not understood.
It was probably operating system based.
I shut down the ethernet interfaces
    `sudo ip link set enp1s0 down` and `sudo ip link set eno1 down` 
launched the brooklyn web console successfully, then put the interfaces back up and launched brooklyn again without issue.

Prior to this I had rebooted a number of times and removed the docker0 bridge interface without success.

Comment: Actually it seems to be the docker0 interface that causes the problem. Resolved with `sudo ip link set docker0 down`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--bindAddress <IP>` option when you launch, with an `<IP>` belonging to a local interface other than loopback (i.e. not `127.0.0.1`).

The error you report means that Brooklyn thinks it cannot open any ports. Since it's unlikely that all those ports are actually in use, what I suspect is happening is that Brooklyn is trying to bind to all interfaces (which is the default, and is also done for completeness if the loopback IP is specified), but there is some interface on your system which does not allow ports to be opened. Brooklyn then concludes that no ports are available. Setting a `bindAddress` explicitly, and to something other than loopback, should force Brooklyn to use only that network interface when binding, avoiding the problematic interface.

It would also be helpful to open an issue for this in [Brooklyn's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BROOKLYN) including details of all network interfaces on your OS. This should help explain the edge case which is breaking port detection so that it can be fixed!